# AIR to Flash Player and vice versa

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash

I'm developing an app that is target for internet and Android. 
For Android I'm using AIR, but for browser I need too use Flash Player. The app will have different stages. Until now, to port an AIR app to browser, i used to strip the code from all AIR functions, but now I can't use this approach since there will be updates for both.

The big problem arises on ANEs and imports.  I will detect the platform using capabilities and know not to got into that code part, but is there a way to flag them so that they won't be imported,like omit trace or at least don't throw errors at compiling.
Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use conditional compiling by way of Compiler Constants. [This article](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation) explains how to do it.

The article is geared toward users of FlashDevelop, but you should be able to accomplish the results regardless of your IDE.

Here's an example:

Let's say you have a config constant called `CONFIG::AIR` and it's set to `false`, the following will compile *only* the code that is outside of the brackets.

```
CONFIG::AIR
{
    import some.air.package.AIROnlyClass;
}
import non.air.package.NonAIRClass;

CONFIG::AIR
{
    var instanceOfAIROnlyClass:AIROnlyClass = new AIROnlyClass();
}
var instanceOfNonAIRClass:NonAIRClass = new NonAIRClass();
```

You can always add a second Compiler Constant (like `CONFIG::NonAIR`), and set it to `true`. That way you can wrap your non-AIR code in conditional statements as well.